# Create a random matrix with full rank

Tags: r

For one of my projects I would like to create several random matrices, which have full rank. Does anybody know a quick way to do this in R or has an idea how to proceed?

Comment: You need to demonstrate that you have attempted to solve this yourself, and describe what problems you encountered. This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 5):

You are overwhelmingly likely to get a full-rank matrix if you generate a matrix with iid elements, with no additional constraints:

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(101)
r <- replicate(1000,rankMatrix(matrix(rnorm(10000),100)))
table(r)  ## all values are equal to 100
```

(Someone who spent more time on the math might be able to prove that the set of reduced-rank matrices within this space of matrices actually has measure 0 ...)

Comment: In order to be not full rank, a square matrix must have its determinant equal to zero. You can write the determinant as a function `f(a11,a12,...,)` of matrix elements. The set of all matrices with zero determinant lie in the surface in which `f=0`. This surface has measure 0 (as you said) in the matrix elements' space.

Comment: If the OP needs a full rank matrix for some real purpose (perhaps he will have to invert it) he might need to worry about numerical instability, so a determinant near 0 might be a problem. Still, a few random repetitions should easily find one.